# OCR at OneNote using VBA

Tags: vba, ocr, onenote

I am aware that inserting a picture that contains text at OneNote, Right-clicking it and selecting **Extract Text from File** allows you to OCR it.

Is it possible to do it with VBA?

So far I have this:  (lol)

```
Dim oneNote As OneNote14.Application

Set oneNote = New OneNote14.Application
```